# OnClickListener not firing

Tags: android

I am creating some buttons pragmatically.  Using the same code from 2 different activities the button fires are not working on one of the activities.  I am a little perplexed as to what I must be overlooking.

```
public class Home_Page_Activity extends Activity {

JSONArray nameArray;
JSONArray valArray;
String[] arrayButtonTitles;
String font;
Context context = null;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params_textview;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params_button;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params_linearlayout;
LinearLayout home_page_layout;
OnClickListener myListener;
Typeface face;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_page_activity);
    WebView wv_Welcome_Message = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv_Welcome_Message);

    context = getApplicationContext();
    params_linearlayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
    params_linearlayout.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    // Set Font
    font = "fonts/aescrawl.ttf";
    face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), font);

    // Reference Layout
    home_page_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.home_page_layout);

    // Set Layout Parameters for XML Elements. (Height, Width,
    // Weight,Padding)
    params_button = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 32, 1.0f);
    params_button.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 30);

    // Load webview if there is connectivity
    if (Repeatables.isNetworkAvailable(context) == true) {
        new InitTask().execute();
    } else {
        wv_Welcome_Message.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    String[] arrayButtonTitles = { "Sub 1", "Sub 2", "Final 1", "Final 2",
            "Category 5", "Category 6", "Category 7", "Category 8",
            "Category 9", "Category 10" };
    Load_Main_Menu(arrayButtonTitles);

myListener = new OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
            Object tag = v.getTag();
            // Do something depending on the value of the tag

                Log.e("TAG","Button "+tag+" pushed");
              if("0".equals(tag.toString())){
                  Log.e("TAG","Hello 1");
              }else  if("21".equals(tag.toString())){
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Sub_Menu_Categories_Main_Activity.class);
                    i.putExtra("whatSubMenuToLoad","none");
                    i.putExtra("whatScreenTypeToLoad","FINALCATEGORY");
                    i.putExtra("categoryId","313");
                    startActivity(i);
              }
          }
        };

}

// Build Home Page XML Layout
public void Load_Main_Menu(String[] buttons) {

    arrayButtonTitles = buttons;
    int numberOfButtons = arrayButtonTitles.length;
    LinearLayout[] ll = new LinearLayout[numberOfButtons];

    // Add Elements to Layout
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfButtons; i++) {

        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText(arrayButtonTitles[i]);
        btn.setTag(i);
        btn.setOnClickListener(myListener);
        btn.setTypeface(face);
        btn.setTextSize(18);
        btn.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(
                R.color.all_button_font_color));
        btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.category_button_background_shape);
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            ll[i] = new LinearLayout(this);
            ll[i].setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            ll[i].addView(btn, params_button);
            home_page_layout.addView(ll[i], params_linearlayout);
        } else {
            ll[i - 1].addView(btn, params_button);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Added my code for myListener.  Left it out sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't initialized `myListener`, there is nothing to fire... Oops :)

Comment: duh sorry i left it out above I had it in there.  ill edit it

Comment: Ok, initialize your listener before calling `Load_Main_Menu()` and you should add `@Override` to the `onClick()` method.

Comment: Great that did it. Lesson learned.  I would have thought that the buttons had to be created first. Thanks

Comment: @Rick. This is semantic but I think the more one understands how Android works, the better. In fact, your buttons are "created" as soon as you use setContentView, or use an inflater, to load your layout. Your layout contains data which define buttons and instances of the Button class are initialised with the  parameters contained in the layout XML.  However, the UI is not built until *after* onCreate, so adding the click listeners in onCreate() makes perfect sense. In fact, to do it elsewhere makes less sense.  Think of onCreate() as where you set up the activity, esp the UI.  Hope this helps.